# Docker Ruby Rack Redis Queues

Tags: ruby, docker, redis, rack

I have long running requests that are handled by a service that I'd like to queue with Redis. So I have a rack application built on top of Passenger and Ruby 2.4. When I make a request to the rack application I'd like the request to go to a Redis process for queueing. I should be able to respond back with a session id and status. **How can I get this working on Docker?**

Answer (score 0):

The main concern of docker container is that it runs only single process. So you have two option to run your application on docker.

1. Break your technology stack 1. rail application 2. passanger 3. Redis and than create separate images of each stack process and use docker-compose to integrate your stack images .
2. With in a single image use supervisor to control your multiple process i.e. run supervisord as CMD in your image.